# How to disable dynamic select box options based on data coming from two tables in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an event booking calendar in PHP/MySQL. In this project, here is my problem -

I have two tables in my mysql database -

1. tb_event_time_slots
2. tb_event_booking

   The table tb_event_time_slots looks as -

   ```
   event_time_slot_id  event_time_slots
   1                   9am-10am
   2                   10am-11am
   3                   11am-12pm
   4                   12pm-1pm
   5                   1pm-2pm
   6                   2pm-3pm
   7                   3pm-4pm
   8                   4pm-5pm
   ```

And table tb_event_booking looks as -

```
id  customer_id     event_time_slot_id  event_date
1   101             1                   22-March-2014
2   102             5                   22-March-2014
```

As you can see that the relation between these two tables is through event_time_slot_id. Now in PHP calendar on date 22-March-2014, a customer with id 101 books an event with id 1 i.e. between a time slot 9am - 10am. In the same way, a customer with id 102 books an event for the time slot 5 i.e. 1pm - 2pm on the same date i.e. 22 March.

So what I am trying to do. Suppose if a particular time slot is already booked on a particular date then it will be disabled i.e. option value in the select list of time slots will be disabled and can not be taken again.

Here is my select list when no event is booked -

```
<select class="seltime" name="seltimeslot">
<option value="">Select a Time</option>
<option value="1">9am-10am</option>
<option value="2">10am-11am</option>
<option value="3">11am-12pm</option>
<option value="4">12pm-1pm</option>
----
----
----
</select>
```

The PHP code which I am using to display select list box is -

```
            $calendar .= "<br /><br /><form method='get' action='confirm_booking.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='event_date' value='$event_date'>
<select name='seltimeslot' class='seltime'>
<option value=''>Select a Time</option>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_event_time_slots` ORDER BY `event_time_slot_id`";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tb_event_booking` ORDER BY `id`";
    $rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        if(($row['event_time_slot_id'] == $row2['event_time_slot_id']) && ($row2['event_date'] == $event_date))
        {
        $status = "Taken";
        $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
        }
        else
        {
        $status = "Available";
        $disabled = "";
     }
        $calendar .= "<option value='" . $row['event_time_slot_id'] . "' $disabled>" . $row['event_time_slots'] . " - $status</option>";
        }
}

$calendar .= "</select><br /><br /><input type='submit' name='btnbook' value='Book Slot' /></form></td>";
}
```

And since I am having two events booked on the same date 22 March for two different time slots, so my above code is not working correctly because of two while loops and gives the following output -

```
<select class="seltime" name="seltimeslot">
<option value="">Select a Time</option>
<option value="1" disabled="disabled">9am-10am</option>
<option value="1">9am-10am</option>
<option value="2">10am-11am</option>
<option value="2">10am-11am</option>
<option value="3">11am-12pm</option>
<option value="3">11am-12pm</option>
<option value="4">12pm-1pm</option>
<option value="4">12pm-1pm</option>
<option value="5">1pm-2pm</option>
<option value="5" disabled="disabled">1pm-2pm</option>
----
-----
-----
```

You can clearly see my problem - the option values i.e. time slots are repeating and there are duplicate values for each time slots. They will more increase if there could be more than 2 events booked on this particular date.

I want to display the time slots which are in the table tb_event_time_slots just only once in the select box.

And the time slots which have been taken in the tb_event_booking table for a particular date for example 22 March or 1 April (in the calendar) will be disable option values and so can not be retaken again.

Here is my requirement -

```
<select class="seltime" name="seltimeslot">
    <option value="">Select a Time</option>
    <option value="1" disabled="disabled">9am-10am</option>
    <option value="2">10am-11am</option>
    <option value="3">11am-12pm</option>
     <option value="4">12pm-1pm</option>
    <option value="5" disabled="disabled">1pm-2pm</option>
----
----
----
</select>
```

So Please tell me what will be best workaround to solve this issue. I think my nested while loop is not good enough to solve this issue. So what changes I need to do to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-write the code without the nested loop

```
$date = '22-March-2014';

$taken_slots = array(); // resets the varaiable for each date
$bookings_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT event_time_slot_id FROM tb_event_booking WHERE event_date=$date");
while($bookings_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookings_qry)) $taken_slots[] = $bookings_row['event_time_slot_id'];
$slots_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tb_event_time_slots");
$calendar = '<select>'; // this will actually be concatinating from all other dates
$calendar .= '<option value="select" disabled="disabled">Select a Time</option>';
while($slots_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slots_qry)) {
    $slot_id = $slots_row['event_time_slot_id']
    $calendar .= '<option value="'.$slot_id.'" ';
    if(in_array($slot_id, $taken_slots)) $calendar .= 'disabled="disabled" ';
    $calendar .= '>'.$slots_row['event_time_slots'].'</option>';
}
$calendar .= '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Actually i was using second query before the first one in my code flow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a very small change that move line of code that is creating dynamic options element out of inner loop ie like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_event_time_slots` ORDER BY `event_time_slot_id`";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tb_event_booking` ORDER BY `id`";
    $rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $cnt = mysql_num_rows($rs2);
    $cntr = 1;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        if(($row['event_time_slot_id'] == $row2['event_time_slot_id']) && ($row2['event_date'] == $event_date))
        {
        $status = "Taken";
        $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
        }
        else
        {
        $status = "Available";
        $disabled = "";
     }

        }
   $cntr++;
    if ($cnt == $cntr) {
   $calendar .= "<option value='" . $row['event_time_slot_id'] . "' $disabled>" . $row['event_time_slots'] . " - $status</option>";
   }
}

$calendar .= "</select><br /><br /><input type='submit' name='btnbook' value='Book Slot' /></form></td>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry it will not work properly. Actually I already tried it. If I move $calendar .= "<option out of inner loop then only the last time slot taken is disabled and not the previous one. Therefore if we have two time slots 9-10 and 1-2 on March 22 then only 1-2 will be disabled and not the 9-10. So what to do?

Comment: sorry for little confusion. Please check updates answer. Little tricky but might be useful. Specially check $cnt and $cntr;

Comment: Sorry again since it did not work either. I am getting the wrong output for 22 March in which 2 time slots have been booked. Only the later time slot is disabled and not the previous one. Moreover using your code is preselecting the 9-10 time slot in each day.