# How to disable drop down option if present in DB

Tags: javascript, php, select, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that is populated by an array. The goal is to have each value selected only once in the drop down to prevent duplicate column values.

I found some javascript that will disable each value after its selected, but if you reload the page, nothing is greyed out in the drop down (obviously).

How would I compare the array values with the database to disable values that are already selected in all the rows on load?

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        $current=$(this);
        $("select").not($current).children(
            "option[value='" + $current.val() + "']"
        ).attr('disabled', "disabled");
    });
});
```

Drop Down Menu

```
<td>
    <div class="grid_content editable">
        <span><?php echo $records['equipment']; ?></span>
        <select class="gridder_input select"
            name="<?php echo encrypt("equipment|".$records['id']); ?>">
            <?php
                foreach($equipment as $equipments) { 
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $equipments; ?>"
                <?php
                    if($equipments == $records['equipment']) {
                        echo 'selected="selected"'; 
                    }
                ?>>
                    <?php echo $equipments; ?>
            </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Is there an easier way to do this than what I've suggested? I think the closest solution I've found would work something like

```
$("select option:contains('Value')").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Where value would be replaced with something that checks the DB. Or something like the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578692/how-to-disable-dynamic-select-box-options-based-on-data-coming-from-two-tables-i) using an if else statement

Comment: you must store clients made changes (menu greyed out or not) serverside. Only this way you can give him page with his settings after page reload. Look into $_sessions, so each client has his own id, aka.. settings. Look into ajax, to send changes to server. Figure out how to you will save changes - in db reffered by ip or temporarry (a cookie lifetime) in Session variable.

Comment: Well users do log into the site, and I've got AJAX setup on some other pages, I've done some research and that's why I'm here. These things are much easier said than done, I can accomplish the same thing in Excel in a matter of seconds, but I'd like to figure out how to get my page to operate in the same fashion.

Comment: Afaik there is attribute *disabled* and it can hold values *true* or *false* Thats all i have,  i think always try not to complicate things, make the code working, it works!.. with time, you will be able to make the code more slick and short, than spending time on perfection now, it really pushes brakes. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Ha yes I'm being very complicated. Static disable is very simple, unfortunately I need a dynamic solution. I mean if I wanted I could just toss a google drive excel file in an iframe and move along, but I'm trying to challenge myself (and others now) I've actually had a few accounts on here, but I delete them after awhile, thanks though